# How to upload image into firebase using .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload, firebase-storage, http-status-code-400

I want to upload images to Firebase in ASP.NET Core
I wrote the following in the index of the controller:
[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJzF.jpg)

This is the function I am sending it to:
[code in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J709m.jpg)

However when I run it I get the following error.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VZP9.jpg)
How can this be solved?

Comment: Please include the minimum reproducible code snippet to simulate your issue. Furthermore, are you getting the token while validating your firebase database? In addition, please check if you are passing the token while sending the request to the firebase.

Comment: var auth=new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(ApiKey));
var a=await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(AuthEmail, AuthPassword);
var cancellation=new CancellationTokenSource();
var task=new FirebaseStorage( Bucket, new FirebaseStorageOptions {AuthTokenAsyncFactory=()=>Task.FromResult(a.FirebaseToken),ThrowOnCancel=true})
.Child("image") .PutAsync(stream, cancellation.Token);
task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s,e)=>Console.WriteLine($"Progress:{e.Percentage} %");
try{
await task;
Console.WriteLine("Download link:"+await task);}
catch (Exception ex) 
{Console.WriteLine(ex);}

Comment: It does manage to do all the code, but just fails at "try". I get the error "Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)."